# Show ping information using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a working on pinging another computer (windows) from my computer(windows). Im using Python code. My code as below

```
import os
hostname = "192.168.1.2"
response = os.system ("ping -c 5 " +hostname)

if response ==0:
    print(hostname, "is up")
else:
    print(hostname, "is down")
```

and i got the output as such

```
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.816 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.584 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.749 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.601 ms

--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.584/0.844/1.470/0.325 ms
('192.168.1.2', 'is up')
```

How can i set it appear something like this after the statistics information?

```
Highest ping is 200 and lowest ping 40
('192.168.1.2', 'is up')
```

or

```
Ping is too high. consider reboot the network
('192.168.1.2', 'is up')
```

Comment: Have you considered using [python-ping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ping/)?

Comment: What is 200 (highest) ? and 40 (lowest) ?

Comment: You mentioned both systems are windows but in output its showing Linux format. `ping -n 5 hostname` and return format will be `Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms`

Comment: sorry. i ping from linux to windows. i was hoping i can get output like "highest ping is 200 and lowest ping is 40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response = os.system ("ping -n 5 " +hostname)
```

even Its unreachable responds will be `0`. It will return `1` only if IP is Wrong.

You may go for some thing similar to

```
try:
    response = subprocess.check_output("ping -n 5"+hostname)
    print response

    if "Destination host unreachable" in response:
        print hostname+" unreachable"

    else:
        print hostname+" Running"
    print '\n'.join(response.split('\n')[8:]) 

except:
    print "Invalid Hostname"
```

based on key words you can check its reachable or not !!

**output:**

```
<hostname> Running
Ping statistics for <hostname>:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

        Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you have two options for something like this.  You can capture the output from the external command (using the *[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)* module that's in the Python standard libraries) or you can use some code (a third party module) which implements "ping" (ICMP ECHO REQUEST) from within your Python code.  There are a few of these listed on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/) (the canonical Python Package Index):

[pyping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyping/0.0.4) is old, and its GitHub link has been broken forever ... but the code is still available directly from PyPI and it still works; I seem to recall that I also had to apply some minor fixes in order to use this as a library rather than as a command line utility).

[ping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping/0.2) is even older (last update 2010) ... but its repository is still live on Bitbucket.

[python3-ping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-ping/2014.05.02.16245f0) is the most recent, and requires Python3. It's [GitHub: python3-ping](https://github.com/emamirazavi/python3-ping) is live, though there haven't been any updates for a couple of years.  (Probably none have been called for ... there aren't any outstanding pull requests, either).

If you search PyPI for other alternatives then I recommend that you use ICMP as your search term.  Searching on "ping" will get you every package that refers to "mapping" and "scraping" and so on --- which amounts to quite a few unrelated hits.

Note that this latter approach, re-implementing the ICMP handling in pure Python, entails running your Python code as root (on Unix/Linux) or with "Administrator" privileges in MS Windows.  That's because ICMP packets must be sent over a "raw" socket ... and those are privileged for a few reasons (including some other types of ICMP packets which can affect how the network treats your whole system rather than just the processes, sockets, that you're working with).  (Here's a guide to [Raw Socket Programming in Python](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/) for more info).

In the former case you capture the output from the command, parse it, and then print it out along with your additional text.  A problem with that approach is that your user won't see any output, by default, until the whole program as executed and exited (all five ping responses have been received or timed out).  You can get around that, if you wish, by using unbuffered I/O ... capturing each line of output as the subprocess emits it and relaying it out before performing the next read() on the subprocess' output pipe.  In the latter case you have more fine grained control over the flow of execution ... and you can even run multiple threads pinging multiple target concurrently, etc.